# RIP, actor Ned Beatty

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Ned Beatty has died, aged 83, after a very active forty-year career in movies and television.  Among his many memorable roles, he was known to superhero fans as Lex Luthor's bumbling sidekick Otis in *Superman* (with a smaller role in *Superman II*).

[image: Otis, Superman, and Lex Luthor]

A generation later, he provided the voice for the murderous Lots-O'-Huggin' Bear in *Toy Story 3*.

[image: Beatty and his alter ego]

Outside the fantasy and science fiction genre, he is possibly best known for his roles in *Deliverance* (his film debut) and his Oscar-nominated, single-scene performance in *Network*.

Comment: Heck of an actor.  *Network* is one of my all-time favorite films, and he was brilliant in his scene.